# Find sum of squared distances between 12 equally spaced points on a unit circle

Tags: geometry, circles

> Let $A_1$, $A_2$, $\dots$, $A_{12}$ be $12$ equally spaced points on a circle with radius $1$. Find
>   $$(A_1 A_2)^2 + (A_1 A_3)^2 + \dots + (A_{11} A_{12})^2.$$
>   The sum includes the square of the distance between any pair of points, so the sum includes $\binom{12}{2} = 66$ terms.

Is there a one-to-one correspondence that can be used here?  I don't see anything that clicks, and I should be able to solve this without trigonometry.

Comment: these are supposed to be complex numbers? roots of unity?

Comment: @JohnFernley  $A_1 A_2$ just means the distance between those two points.

Comment: Related: [Sum of Distances between Points on a Regular n 
n-gon](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308876/sum-of-distances-between-points-on-a-regular-n-gon). Expect some trigonometry, though.

Comment: This is $6$ times the sum of the $11$ terms $(A_1A_k)^2$. Since $A_1A_7$ is a diameter, each triangle $A_1A_kA_7$ has a right angle at $A_k$ for every $2\leqslant k\leqslant6$ and every $8\leqslant k\leqslant12$ hence $$(A_1A_k)^2+(A_1A_{8-k})^2=(A_1A_k)^2+(A_kA_7)^2=(A_1A_7)^2$$ Thus, $$\sum_{k=2}^{12}(A_1A_k)^2=(A_1A_7)^2+\sum_{k=2}^{6}(A_1A_k)^2+(A_1A_{8-k})^2=6\cdot(A_1A_7)^2=24$$ and the sum in the question is $$6\cdot24=144=12^2$$ For $2n$ points, the answer is $(2n)^2$.

Comment: @Did I think your comment is the better answer given so far. You should turn it into an answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

By a rotation, we can assume that $A_i = \omega^i$ where $\omega$ is a primitive 12th root of 1. For ease of calculation, let us add the terms $(A_iA_i)^2$. Then, if $S$ is the sum we want, we have 
\begin{align*}
2S &= \sum_{i=1,j=1}^{12,12}(A_iA_j)^2
\end{align*}
Now, $$(A_iA_j)^2 = |\omega^i - \omega^j|^2 = |\omega^{i-j}-1|^2 $$
Also, 
$$|1-\omega^i|^2 = (1-\omega^i)(1-\omega^{12-i}) = 1 - \omega^i - \omega^{12-i} + 1 $$
and hence
\begin{align*}
2S &= 12\sum_{i=1}^{12}(2 - \omega^{i}- \omega^{12-i}) \\
&=288 - 24\sum_{i=1}^{12}\omega^i
\end{align*}
Now, $\omega^i$ are the roots of the equation $z^{12}-1 = 0$ and hence the second term above is zero. Thus $S=144$.